# Raspberry Pi connection with Arduino over XRF continuous sensor monitoring

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, monitoring, pyserial

I'm trying to make a system for monitoring sensor continuously including registering the time when the sensors are offline (not reachable by the server).

The system is based on Raspberry Pi as server and Arduino Leonardo as node with sensors and the data is communicated from Arduino to Raspberry via XRF.

I'm using Python script with pySerial for collecting data. My Python skills are poor and I need help to figure out how to continue monitoring when the connection between Arduino and Raspberry is lost and when the connection is re-established the sensor data could be collected again without restarting the script.

the Python script follows:

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)

while True:
   #Arduino sends sensor analog reading when receiving the letter "k"
   ser.write('k') 
   datetime = str(datetime.now())
   print(datetime)
   print(ser.readline())
```

At the moment once the server looses connection to the client the script will stop.

Comment: how does your client stops ? your are using one single Arduino, or multiple ones ? your serial device is constant ?

Comment: The server script stops not the client. I tried at first with one client. serial is constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need periodically reopen the connection, and also log the moments when the connection is lost? something like this...

```
import serial
import time
from datetime import datetime

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)

while True:
   if ser.isOpen()==True:
       ser.write('k') # Arduino sends sensor analog reading when receiving the letter "k"
       datetime = str(datetime.now())
       print(datetime)
       print(ser.readline())
       time.sleep(1) # take a break so that you dont thrash the sensor with requests all the time
   else:
       try:
           print "Lost connection at %s" % str(datetime.now())
           ser.open()              
       except:
           print "Cannot open port."
           exit(-1)
```

Comment: Looks like this should do it. I will test it in the evening and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Code seems to run well ... for now :).